# Weird behaviour in TSQL min function

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
ID      Code
647     1026836
248289  1026836
250080  1026836
```

I try to get the min of id:

```
 SELECT  min(rtrim(id))  ,   
            Code
    FROM     [XXX] 
  where  Code = '1026836'
    GROUP   BY Code
```

result:

```
ID      Code
248289  1026836
```

Why? It should give:

```
ID  Code
647 1026836
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: Why do you rtrim a numeric value? (Is it numeric?)

Answer (score 2):

Check your data types! Its possibly doing the min() on a non-numerical data type. You wouldnt need to trim a numeric data type.

Answer (score 1):

nevermind:

```
  min(cast(id as bigint))
```

did the trick as the id was nvarchar

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!